# java map toString() override

Tags: java, dictionary, overriding, tostring

```
System.out.println(map);
```

so result is {A=2, B=4, C=5 ..}
but i want print

```
A 2
B 4
C 5
...
```

So, my processor's hint is map toSting() override,
but i don't understand

this is my code

```
class MapManager2 {
public static Map<String, Double> readData(String fileName) {
    Map<String, Double> mapOfData;
    Map<String, Double> sortedByValue = null;

    try {
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File(fileName)); // read file
        mapOfData = new TreeMap<>(); // create Map to store the values

        while (file.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = file.nextLine(); // read the line
            String[] words = line.split("\\s+"); // split the item and price by space
            Double price = Double.parseDouble(words[1]); // parse the double price
            mapOfData.put(words[0], price); // put the data in map
        }

        /* Sort the map on basis of value*/
        sortedByValue = mapOfData.entrySet()
                .stream().sorted((Map.Entry.<String, Double>comparingByValue()))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Input file not found");
    }
    return sortedByValue;
}

}
public class Problem21 {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, Double> map = MapManager2.readData("input.txt");
    if (map == null) {
        System.out.println("Input file not found.");
        return;
    }
    System.out.println(map);
}
```

}

Comment: If you want to do this, you will have to create a new class that extends LinkedHashMap, overrides `toString()`, and then return a map of that class from your MapManager2 instead. This is possible, but not a common or good way to customize the format of a map.

Answer (score 2):

Your prof is telling you to override the toString method of the Map class.
I think the best idea is an anonymous override.

```java
Map<String, String> test = new HashMap<>() {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder stb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : this.entrySet()) {
            stb.append(entry.getKey()).append(" ")
                    .append(entry.getValue()).append("\n");
        }
        return stb.toString();
    }
};
```

Note that I don't have any way to chexk this code for errors right now, so you may have to fix some names.

Comment: hello, Can i ask ?

Answer (score 1):

> So, my processor's hint is map toSting() override, but i don't understand

I don't know who your 'processor' is (professor?), but that's a dumb hint.

overriding things makes sense when you're subclassing something. Don't subclass map, that's... not what you want.

instead of passing 'map' to `System.out.println`, which will result in println invoking `.toString()` on that object and printing the resulting string, make your own string:

```
String print = map.entrySet().stream()
    // convert each element in the map to the string "KEY VALUE"
    .map(x -> x.getKey() + " " + x.getValue())
    // collect em by joining em, separating each "KEY VALUE" string with a newline
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
System.out.println(print);
```

Comment: So, system.out.println(map) is never chaned.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "processor's hint" but you don't really need to override `toString`. Simpler is to just convert the map to the string you want:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue())
    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
```

Or if you just want to print the map directly:

```
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + " " + v));
```

Answer (score 0):

To override the toString() method, extend TreeMap class and replace your TreeMap instance with new class.

```java
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

public class MyTreeMap extends TreeMap<String,Double> {
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        this.entrySet().forEach(me -> {
            System.out.printf("%s %s%n", me.getKey(), me.getValue());
        });
        return result.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: hello Can i ask question?

Comment: Sure. (BTW, stackoverflow is a place for exchanging technical knowledge, so you don't need to ask before but just write down your question. It's not unpolite, if you are worrying. :-) )

Comment: class MyTreeMap.. because i don't understand about override..

Comment: please help me...:(

Comment: Hmm, I am sorry to say but, for such basic level questions, stackoverflow is not suitable and you should search and read various "java programming tutorial" sites where you can get detailed explanations on what you should know.